# ATI driver bug and rendering to a texture 2d array in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics-programming

I am trying to render to a `texture2Darray` in OpenGL, with a similar setup as descriped in [this post](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=280589). My question is, if anyone has gotten this to work on ATI hardware? Or is there still a bug in the driver, preventing multi layered rendering? The bug is also mentioned in the forum post.

Answer (score 1):

Curious. The extension in question seems to be gl_ext_texture_array.

According to the OpenGL extensions viewer 3.34 database, that should be supported by a wide variety of ATI hardware, and even one S3 chip too. The only discussion about it that I could find was http://forums.amd.com/devforum/messageview.cfm?catid=392&threadid=120024&enterthread=y where nobody answered the question, but there seem to be some issues. Judging from that thread, the issue seems to be related to clamping; you may want to try with the wrap mode instead.